# Force a connection via SSL3 to detect POODLE vulnerability

Tags: tls, web-browser, known-vulnerabilities

I have been reading up on the POODLE vulnerability.  From my understanding, and correct me if I am wrong, you need to allow connections to be made via SSLv3 on the server.

The server I am currently running defaults to TLS 1.0 in the browsers I have tested but I am not certain if the connection will downgrade to SSL 3.0 if the client asked for it.

Is there a way in Chrome or any other browser to force the use SSL 3.0.  I merely want to test if my site(s) permit connection via SSL 3.0 or not.

Comment: Possible Dupe of the question https://superuser.com/questions/827377/disabling-ssl-3-on-64bit-chrome-for-windows please check the Stack Exchange network before asking questions to make sure your awnser isn't on it already :)

Comment: @Lighty I am not asking how to disable it - I am asking how to force a connection via SSL3 - I have rephrased the question to clarify.

Comment: Note that just because SSLv3 is used on a connection does not mean it is vulnerable to POODLE. You can also disable CBC ciphering to prevent the attack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily matter what your server uses by default - most servers and clients are configured to negotiate the highest protocol available. A major aspect of the POODLE attack is that an attacker can cause connection failures in a higher (non-vulnerable) protocol, and **downgrade the victim to SSL3**. *Then* they can exploit the vulnerability in SSL 3.

Source: http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html

So the client doesn't need to ask for the connection to be downgraded - an attacker with access to network traffic can do this. Any client that *supports* SSL 3 is potentially vulnerable (if the server does as well and [SCSV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bmoeller-tls-downgrade-scsv-02) isn't enabled both ends).

But yes, most of the browsers allow you to disable SSL/TLS versions, and in some cases you could choose to disable newer protocols.

- In **Internet Explorer**, you can disable SSL/TLS protocols from Internet Options > Advanced.
- In **FireFox**, you can set the [security.tls.version.max and security.tls.version.min](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*) FireFox preferences to select a specific version.
- In **Google Chrome**, you can use the --ssl-version-max and --ssl-version-min command line flags to select a specific protocol verison. The accepted values are: "ssl3", "tls1", "tls1.1", or "tls1.2". [How to set command line flags on Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags).

It should go without saying that you should typically only use such methods to disable old insecure protocols (like SSL 2 and 3 currently).

Answer (score 4):

Firefox browser provides the easiest way to do such testing via the advanced settings in `about:config`

[image: about:config]

where [security.tls.version](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*) can be of the following values

- **0 - SSLv3** (set max and min value to this)
- 1 - TLSv1.0
- 2 - TLSv1.1
- 3 - TLSv1.2

What you will see when the website does not support SSLv3 is this:

[image: connection error]

Please remember to set it back to `max 3` and `min 1` after use.

Comment: Funny, after setting both to `0`, I still see the connection is established with TLSv1.2... (btw, I had `max` set to `4` by default).

Answer (score 0):

Any connection made on `SSL v3` and using `CBC` Ciphers is vulnerable to `Poodle` attack. Browsers (Older browsers and other clients) will negotiate SSL as we write about it.

Although most have disabled SSL by default and only work with TLS.

Note that there is a new `Poodle on TLS` vulnerability that we will not talk about in this thread.

The only way to disable such a `Poodle on SSL` attack is to disable SSL completely (v3 and earlier) or if you really need SSL v3 for compatibility with older clients, remove any `CBC` ciphers from the list of cipher suites that the server will support.

If you want to test whether your site supports SSL, you can use [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) or the [Symantec CertChecker](https://ssltools.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp) to name a few.