# Is it possible to enable SSLv3 on Firefox 49.0.1?

Tags: tls, firefox

As we all know SSLv3 protocol is broken but I am doing university project regarding SSLv3 security.

Is it possible to enable sslv3 on Firefox 49.0.1? I tried changing the value in `about:config` of `security.tls.version.min` to 0 but it didn't work.

Anyone know how to enable this?

Comment: is there any reason not to use an older version of Firefox?

Comment: Do you have an SSLv3-only site that can be used for testing?

Comment: @Z.T. Yes I do have

Comment: If you dont mind using Internet explorer:  http://security.stackexchange.com/a/108679/106793